# How to implement share to twitter with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, twitter-share, react-share

I want to let users share images from my website to twitter.

I used this module [react-share](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share) to implement this.But it doesn't give an option to share images.

My code looks likes this.

```
import { ShareButtons, ShareCounts, generateShareIcon, } from 'react-share';

const {
    FacebookShareButton,
    GooglePlusShareButton,
    LinkedinShareButton,
    TwitterShareButton,
    PinterestShareButton,
    VKShareButton,
} = ShareButtons;

<TwitterShareButton
    url={shareUrl}
    title={title}
    className="shareBtn col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
    <a className="twitter"><i className="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</TwitterShareButton>
```

Please help me fix this on how to share images to twitter.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please add `<TwitterIcon>` in your code

```
<TwitterShareButton
        url={shareUrl}
        title={title}
        className="Demo__some-network__share-button">
        <TwitterIcon
          size={32}
          round />
      </TwitterShareButton>
```

Comment: How to get the current url

Comment: I know it is super old, but... with window.location.href

Answer (score 3):

[react-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share)  does not support image uploading. You can only share url, title and hashtags with **TwitterShareButton**.
Main image of page will be showed when you add url.

Also your icon is missing, this is how you can add icon.

```
<TwitterShareButton url={url} title={title}>
    <button className="btn btn-circle">
        <i className="fab fa-twitter"> </i>
    </button>
</TwitterShareButton>
```

Comment: that same method isn't working with Pinterest and Instagram share.

Answer (score 1):

You can not share rich content to twitter using this widget, only way is to host your image on static url and share that url via `TwitterShareButton`

Sample react-share code snippet at https://samvikshana.weebly.com/blog/react-share-social-share-widgets

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is that you need to pass a child (Icon) to the ShareButton and also IMPORT it.

Example:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      TwitterShareButton,
      TwitterIcon,
    } from "react-share";
    class Quotes extends Component {
    
     render() {
return( <div>
     <TwitterShareButton
              title="Hello"
             url="https://stackoverflow.com/"
            >
             
              <TwitterIcon size={32} round />
            </TwitterShareButton>    

</div>
       )
    }
 }
```

It's a very nice tool.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context to your code, for example the imports. Also try to use the TwitterShareButton example to match the question.