# How to share image to twitter from React

Tags: reactjs, twitter

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144386/how-to-implement-share-to-twitter-with-react-js) suggests that you can't use [react-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share) to post an image directly from react to twitter inside of a tweet.

Is there another library/method that's available?

Comment: [Twitter web intents](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/guides/web-intent) doesn't support images so no this isn't possible.